# Upper bound on the norm of a solution to a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, upper-lower-bounds

I have a linear system $Ax = b$ where $A$ is an $m \times n$ integral matrix and I know there exists at least one solution. I want an upper bound on the $\ell_2$ norm $\|x\|$ such that $\|x\|$ is minimized over all possible solutions. To state the problem differently I would like to find an $x$ such that $\|x\|$ has a nice upper bound.

Preferably, I would like the bound to be in terms of $m,n,b$ and properties of $A$ such as its singular values or determinants of square submatrices. However, I'd be interested in seeing bounds involving other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here's one short example offered as an answer:
Suppose A is a matrix that projects 3d space onto the x-axis. $\text{diag}\,(1,0,0)$, if you will. Say $b=(5,0,0)^T$. Then any $x$ of the form $(5,p,q)^T$ will satisfy your equation, no matter how huge $p$ and $q$ are. The solutions seem to be unbounded.
You can probably formalize this with the rank-nullity theorem or something. If $A$'s range has the same dimension as the dimension of $x$, then there's precisely one solution, which is boring. Otherwise, if $A$ is 'lossy' in some sense, then there are some subspaces of the domain that $A$ is collapsing to zero, and $x$ can have as big of a component it wants in these subspaces.)

Aight, ignore all that, I think I got it!

So basically, if we want $x$ to be as small as possible, let's make sure it has no components in $A$'s nullspace (because any such component would add to $x$'s size unnecessarily). So, $x$ should be orthogonal to the nullspace of $A$, i.e. in the rowspace of $A$, i.e. i the columnspace of $A^T$.

Now, consider all $y$ that satisfy $Ay=b$. If we project such a $y$ down to the columnspace of $A^T$, we are done. Fortunately, we have a simple tool to project stuff to columnspaces of matrices - this is where the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse comes in. The [wikipedia page on projection matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix) has some nice intuition on this.

Okay, so we get that $x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$. How to find an upper bound on size?
$$\|x\|^2=b^T(AA^T)^{-1^T}A\,A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b=b^T(AA^T)^{-1^T}b=\langle b, (AA^T)^{-1^T}b\rangle$$
So by Cauchy-Schwarz we get
$$\|x\|^2\leq\|b\|\,\|(AA^T)^{-1^T}b\|=\|b\|^2\,\|(AA^T)^{-1^T}\hat{b}\|$$
Where $\hat{b}=b/\|b\|$. Now notice that in the end we're basically looking at the operator norm for $(AA^T)^{-1^T}$, which is bounded above by the biggest singular value. And we also know that transposing doesn't change the singular values, and taking the inverse also inverts the singular values, so
$$\|x\|^2\leq\|b\|^2\cdot\frac{1}{\text{smallest singular value of }AA^T}$$

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't written clearly enough. I'm aware that the norms of the solutions may be unbounded. What I want to say is that there always exists a solution whose norm "small." That is, there exists an $x$ such that $\|x\|$ is upper bound by some nice function. If we extend your example to $n$ dimensions it seems we can always find a solution whose norm is bound by $O(n)$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your question and ended up answering something stupid. Let me take another shot. I think the smallest $x$ that satisfies $Ax=b$ should be given by $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$. I'm on mobile so will try explaining how i got that later. Until then please check if it kinda makes sense?

Comment: This is the Penrose-Moore inverse of $A$? I recall reading that it should yield the minimum vector that is mapped to $b$ but I have no intuition about why that is true. Assuming it is true we just need to compute a bound on the size of $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$ and we are done.

Comment: The pseudoinverse is mostly used for projection. I've edited the answer, please check it out!

Comment: This answer is good. I think my only remaining question is what assumptions do I need to make about $A$ to guarantee that $(AA^T)^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the rows of $A$ should be linearly independent for that.